# Resistance to a nanoscale system like hydrogen atom?

Tags: electrical-resistance, hydrogen, nanoscience

Can we talk about the resistance to a nanoscale system? For example, the hydrogen atom. It is obvious that the conventional resistance formula
$$R=\rho \dfrac{L}{A}$$
be unable to characterize the resistance of the hydrogen atom. Here $L$ and $A$ will be ill-defined.

Comment: First you must define what you even mean by "resistance of the hydrogen atom" in the first place.

Comment: Electrical conductivity is a bulk phenomenon. The electrical conductivity of a single atom is meaningless.

Comment: @John Rennie: Conventionally we just talk about the resistance of bulk materials. But now we need to talk about these concepts for nanoscale systems, such as in FET, molecular FET, in which the central channel consists of a few atoms. Then this question is not meaningful.

Comment: @probably_someone: consider a physical configuration or nanoscale system: source+hydrogen+drain.

Comment: Applying a bulk concept (where conductance is an average over a large number of possible paths) to your hydrogen atom (with perhaps only a few allowable ways of moving an electron across it) seems ill advised. So, yes, you can talk about resistance, and can measure and likely compute it, but it will not be related to a bulk concept.

Answer (score 1):

Considering nanoscale systems you have to formulate your question in terms of quantum mechanics. A simplified model where you can easily identify a [(probability) current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current), is the tunneling process. Given a arbitrary potential barrier (textbook examples: potential step, potential well) and an electron coming from minus infinity, you can calculate the probability for this electron to be reflected or [transmitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_coefficient#Quantum_mechanics). The resulting reflection and transmission coefficients are a measure of the resistance of "passing through the potential".

This scheme holds for single-particle problems, but cannot easily be generalized to many-particles.